# Ошибка в переводе описания тегов или баг

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки

Интересовался описаниями нескольких тегов и заметил, что часть перевода на русский язык не корректна.
В верхнем левом углу описания меток на англоязычном SO сайте есть надпись `About` и далее тег которым мы интересуемся:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На русскоязычном SO, это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то надпись "О компании" и далее запрашиваемый тег, выглядит странно. О компании чего? тега?

Comment: Ответили это классно..., но за столько дней так ничего и не поменялось. Даже дословный перевод это "о" или "об"...

Comment: И не поменяется.

Comment: Печаль.........