# Как "метка" стала "компанией"?

Tags: дефект, локализация, описание-метки

Попробуйте зайти в описание любой метки, например в [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения, ну, пожалуйста]

Я так понимаю, что вместо "о компании" должно быть "о метке". Баг локализации?

Comment: Ты уже четвёртый или пятый))

Comment: @Qwertiy кажется, настала пора пинать главного по международным сайтам.

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну давай - ты ж переводчик ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy у кого вообще из нас ромб приближённого к сотрудникам компании?

Comment: @älёxölüt, зато меня даже в транзификсе нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy непозволительная роскошь для модератора! К тому же в ближайшем будущем [явный транзифекс будет не нужен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8188/176217), наверное.

Comment: @älёxölüt так проблема то не в трансе, а в том, что ключик оригинальный один.

Comment: @Suvitruf это надо Qwertiy адресовать, а не мне :)

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8179/262779