# Странное название в шапке страницы описания метки

Tags: дефект, локализация, описание-метки

Перешел из чата по ссылке с меткой и на странице описания метки обнаружил такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info

Посмотрел несколько других меток - тоже самое. Что делает "О компании" на странице описания метки? Это баг или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: За месяц никаких подвижек, хотя уже четвертый или пятый раз топик такой создают :(

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8179/262779 и https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8222/262779